# Store Jmeter sampler properties value using beanshell preprocessor

Tags: jmeter, preprocessor, beanshell

I've a test plan with TCP sampler with HOST and PORT defined using TCP sampler config.

I have defined the 'port' value for the TCP connection defined in TCP sampler config and I need this value (TCPSampler.port=3001) to be part of request to the server.

I am trying to use beanshell pre-processor to capture and store it on a user defined variable.

Any idea about how to achieve this.

Advanced thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following code into "Text to send" input

```
TCPSampler.port=${__BeanShell(ctx.getCurrentSampler().getPort();,port)}
```

Broken down it consists of:

1. [__Beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) function which allows to execute arbitrary beanshell code in any place of the script
2. `ctx` - is the shortcut to the instance of [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class. See JavaDoc for all available methods
3. [getCurrentSampler()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getCurrentSampler()) - is aforementioned JMeterContext class method which provides access to the instance of the current sampler
4. [getPort](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/tcp/sampler/TCPSampler.html#getPort()) is the method of [TCPSampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/tcp/sampler/TCPSampler.html) class as in your case it will be TCP sampler

So __Beanshell function executes the script and saves result into `port` variable which can be later accessed anywhere in current thread group.

For Beanshell PreProcessor (if you still want to use it) relevant code will look like:

```
int port = sampler.getPort();
vars.put("port", String.valueOf(port));
```

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for comprehensive information on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter. 
`